# How can I restart samba ONLY when there isn't any files being transferred

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm trying to find a way to do this. Right now I have a script that will only allow samba to be reset by running "smbstatus", but it isn't very reliable (shows locked files when a Windows client has mapped a share, with no file activity).

Is there any way to detect when Samba has files being transferred?

NOTE: Only active file transfers, not mapped clients

EDIT: Here is what my script looks like

```
until sudo smbstatus | grep "No locked files"
do
    echo "Processes Running..."
    sleep 5
    echo ""
done
sudo service smbd restart
echo "Restarted SMB"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `deadtime` setting to kill child `smbd` processes that are not being actively used.

Example, which kills a child process after it has been unused for 10 minutes:

```
deadtime = 10
```

The documentation notes, amongst other things, that

> The deadtime only takes effect if the number of open files is zero.
>
> Most clients have an auto-reconnect feature when a connection is broken so in most cases this parameter should be transparent to users.
>
> Using this parameter with a timeout of a few minutes is recommended for most systems.

Using this scheme you can count the number of child processes and perform your reset when there is only the parent process remaining. (Mind you, it might be luck but I have not recently had any problem restarting the parent `smbd` process even while child processes are still running.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just added my script to the question... when any Windows client maps out a share, "smbstatus" will report there are locked files. I tried using deadtime, but Windows keeps the connection alive somehow by just being connected to it